# find $D$ of $(D+A)$ for $diag((D+A)^-1)=k$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, inverse-problems

I am wondering whether it is possible to derive $D$ for

$diag((D+A)^{-1})=k$

where

- $diag()$ produces a vector of diagonal elements of a squared matrix,
- $D$ is an unknown diagonal matrix with possible values between zero and $\infty$, where it is known that $D$ exists,
- $A$ is a known positive definite symmetric matrix, and
- $k$ is a known vector of positive values between $>0$ and $diag(A^{-1})$

Thanks

Comment: For clarity, what does the $\operatorname{diag}$ refer to? It usually refers to a map that takes a vector in $\Bbb{R}^n$ and produces a diagonal matrix with the entries of the vector down the diagonal. It seems that you're going in the opposite direction here: is $\operatorname{diag} M$ the diagonal of $M$ as a vector? Or does it refer to some kind of diagonalisation process?

Comment: Also, this isn't C++: you can use just one $=$ to denote the two vectors are the same.

Comment: This is confusing, but you seem to want to find a suitable $D$ if you know the eigenvalues of $(D+A)^{-1}$ (which is equivalent to knowing the eigenvalues od $D/A$ (also it is clearly symmetric but are you sure it is definite positive? I would say yes but you have to prove it)

Comment: Since $\big((D+A)^{-1}\big)_{ii}\le (A^{-1})_{ii}$ for each $i$, your problem is not solvable if $k_i>(A^{-1})_{ii}$ for some $i$.

Comment: $diag(M)$ produces a vector of diagonal elements of a squared matrix $M$

Comment: I cannot see how the eigenvalues of $(D+A)^{-1}$ can be known. $k$ is the the vector of eigenvalues, it is the vector of diagonal elements

Comment: As pointed out above $k_i$ is always $\leq (A^{-1})_{ii}$